# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '25' for key 'tbl_item_item_ID_UNIQUE'

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have a table named `inventory` and it has 04 fields. They are  `qty`,`inventory_dateTime`,`tbl_item_item_ID`, and `tbl_branch_branch_ID`.

`tbl_item_item_ID` and `tbl_branch_branch_ID` both are primary keys and currently the table has (1000 ,2015-11-12 19:01:04 ,25 ,2) values respectively.

I wanted to add other data for the same table and values for `tbl_item_item_ID` and `tbl_branch_branch_ID` would be (25 ,3)
[*that simply means add 25th item_id from another branch to the inventory*]

But it gives

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '25' for key 'tbl_item_item_ID_UNIQUE'

How would I solve this? Help me please.

Comment: @ Fred 
Ops sorry I didn't know that I will do that .. Thanks for your advise ..

Answer (score 0):

this violation means that you are trying to insert an entry that duplicates an allready existing key. Or to put that simply bl_item_item_ID = 25 allready exists in the table and since that is a unique id column it can not be duplicated (if you are supposed have duplicate entries for that column, than maybe your issue is that you have tbl_item_item_ID and tbl_branch_branch_ID as 2 unique ids, but what you need is one unique id made of 2 columns)

Comment: yep I know that but I have added both tbl_item_item_ID,tbl_branch_branch_ID  as primary key. So when take both together it doesn't become duplication , Is there any query to consider those two fields are primary key together ?

Comment: if you are using any GUI for your database you can view the keys of your table. If you have 2 x unique keys, that is wrong, what you should have is one key made of 2 elements. if you are not using any GUI, try using this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-index.html

Answer (score 0):

Okay here the picture of table description and reorders which i have added alredy .[image] 
[image]

Now I wanted to add some values as new record (new row)  which item_ID = 25 and branch_ID = 3

Comment: Ok, so i see you are using PhpMyAdmin. in the table structure tab you should see something like indexes (dont quite remembe the layout of that tool, but anyway, when you look at your indexes you should see something like: unique_id1: tbl_item_item_ID,tbl_branch_branch_ID  and not unique_id1:tbl_item_item_ID, unique_id2:tbl_branch_branch_ID

Comment: Thanks Evey one i found a problem my self. I have added item_ID as unique here and same time item_ID and branch_ID are primary key, because I could not add same key repetitively for item_ID. Now I removed it and thanks for all of your effort .. ! Thank you very much ...